# Debug yield return in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on some older code that is using multiple nested yield return statements. Is there a setting to cause VS to iterate through this so that I can set a break point and view the contents of an object?

**Edit:**

I used ToList() on the object that I am looking and I am still unable to view the contents of the object.

[image]

Again, I'm wondering if there is a setting that will make visual studio ignore the normal functionality of an existing `yield return`

Comment: No, there's nothing in Visual Studio that will change how the C# compiler treats `yield break`.

Comment: Are you running in release mode? If so the optimization may have eliminated `thing` because it's not being used below.

Comment: @Jmaurier, If you get any latest information, please share it here, actually this issue is also not very clearly for me, my understanding is that you want to use the debug watch window to view the object during you debug this project, am I right? If so, I agree with Dec's suggestion, you have to step into it. Like the first sample here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, you could view the Power(2, 8) in debug watch window after you step into Power iterator function.

Comment: In addition, we could use the Conditions Breakpoints to change the debugging Conditions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/10/06/new-breakpoint-configuration-experience-in-visual-studio-2015/, but not very sure that whether it is what you want to get for this issue "ignore the normal functionality of an existing yield return.".

Answer (score 3):

The method wont run until you enumerate into it, therefore your break points will never be hit, try calling .ToList() on it.

Comment: The question is asking how to set a breakpoint, not saying that it isn't being hit.

Comment: "Is there a setting to cause VS to iterate through this so that I can set a break point?" Reads to me that he isn't aware of the difference.

Comment: Then by all means, ask him if he misstated his question so it can be corrected if appropriate.  As it is though, your answer is simply wrong.